# Can I export a specific table in an org file to csv from the command line?

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file with multiple tables

```
$ cat ~/foo.org
#+Title: hello world

* section 1

lorem ipsum

#+TBLNAME: first-table
| i      | want | to    |
| export | this | table |

#+TBLNAME: second-table
| this | table | is        |
| not  | as    | important |
```

This file is updated regularly. I have a perl script that parses the `csv` file obtained from issuing `M-x org-table-export` on `first-table`. I would like to be able to export `first-table` to csv from the command line so I don't have to do this manually every time. Is this possible?

Comment: In order to get the contents of the table in an Org file you could do `(org-babel-ref-resolve "first-table")` - this will give you the table as a list, and then call `orgtbl-to-csv` on that list. See the documentation of `orgtbl-to-csv` for additional arguments. You could then run Emacs in batch mode to execute your function either using `--eval` or `-f` options.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can look for the table by name, and use `org-table-export` to export it.  You can put the function in a file, load it, and batch export.  Something like this maybe:

setup.el:

```el
(require 'org)

(defun my-tbl-export (name)
  "Search for table named `NAME` and export."
  (interactive "s")
  (outline-show-all)
  (let ((case-fold-search t))
    (if (search-forward-regexp (concat "#\\+TBLNAME: +" name) nil t)
    (progn
      (next-line)
      (org-table-export (format "%s.csv" name) "orgtbl-to-csv")))))
```

Then with your example file, you can batch export like this:

```
$ emacs --batch foo.org -l setup.el --eval '(my-tbl-export "first-table")'
```

My search for the table is a bit crude, but it works.